# Json POST HTTP from Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, http, post

I am trying to do a simple POST JSON from my windows phone application, but am stuck with how to do it.
Can you please help, with example code if possible.

Comment: I am new to c# programming.
I am unable to figure out how to post json objects from a windows phone. i have tried the codes on MSDN and a few from stackoverflow too, but none have worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a try with this "[Windows Phone POST client](http://postclient.codeplex.com/releases/view/66457)". But I suggest that it's much better when you dig into this client and get to know the process of POST operation in Windows Phone .